# Can I get 2560x1440 resolution on external monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, high-sierra

I have a mid-2015 MacBook Pro running High Sierra. I normally use it as a desktop computer in clamshell mode with an external monitor.

I just replaced my 24-inch external monitor with a 32-inch monitor. The new monitor is an Acer EB321HQU-B, which is supposed to support up to 2560x1440 resolution.

According to the [technical specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp719?locale=en_US) my Mac is supposed to support

> full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on up to two external displays, both at millions of colors.

and

> Support for 3840-by-2160 resolution at 30Hz

I have the new monitor connected via a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter.

But the best I can get is 1920x1080, which is the same as my old monitor. In Display preferences, the only options I see in Scaled are 1600x900, 1080p, 1080i, and 720p, whether I select 60Hz or 30Hz. So I can't show any more on the screen, it's just all scaled up 33%.

Is there some way I can take advantage of the new monitor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the cable you’re using to connect the monitor to the computer.

The easiest way to ensure that you have the full resolution is to use a standard mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable and you should be able to use the full resolution without problems.

You can also use a mini-DisplayPort to DVI cable, but these are usually harder to come by in a standard home electronics store.

Last but not least, it might be possible to get the full resolution by using a better HDMI cable. You'll need one that supports HDMI 1.3 or 1.4 to support the 2560x1440 resolution.

Comment: Thanks. I went to Staples, they didn't have any Mini-DP to DP in stock, but they ordered one for me. Assuming it solves the problem I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I probably won't be able to accept the answer for a couple of weeks; the cable may not arrive until Friday, and I'll be away on vacation. I'm just wondering if you think it will also address another issue I'm seeing: when I do screen sleep, the monitor backlight stays on. Will it be able to go completely black with DP?

Comment: The cable came today, the result is beautiful.

Comment: The issue with screen sleep is actually something else. It's ignoring the "Put the screen to sleep" setting in Energy Saver, and showing the screen saver, which is set to a black screen. I didn't have this problem with my previous VGA monitor. I'll open a new question.

Comment: Sounds good with the cable :-)

Comment: Yes, the sound is good, too :)

Comment: Can you look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354344/macbook-pro-wont-put-external-display-to-sleep-when-idle regarding the screen sleep issue?

Answer (score 2):

Why did you not use a Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter? For example, [this item](https://www.microcenter.com/product/486257/mini-displayport-male-to-dvi-i-female-adapter-6-in---white).

A mini-DisplayPort actually has the DVI signals. Only the jack is smaller. The converter does not need to convert the signals. There are just wires connected between the smaller  mini-DisplayPort pins and the larger DVI jack pins.

Comment: Because that's what the MicroCenter salesman sold me.

Comment: The monitor came with an HDMI cable, so he sold me the adapter for it.

Comment: Can I assume since you have a HDMI port, that there is also a DVI port, but no Display port (DP)?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I know the monitor - it has HDMI, DVI and DisplayPort as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Right, it has all those ports, but the only cable I have is HDMI. I've ordered a new cable.